# Why can I see the glow from my TV remote's LED if it is supposed to emit in the infrared?

Tags: photons, biophysics, biology, infrared-radiation

The TV remote light emissions being >700nm are supposed to be invisible right? Same goes for proximity sensor on phone and laser focus on phone's  back camera.

But how could, me and 3 more people I asked, seem to be able to see them all and describe them with dim red glow? Can you see it? I want to know what percentage of people can see it.

Note, I've used the following remote brands for test ─ Bpl, Sony, and Samsung.

Comment: I suspect the manufacturers source lots of different kinds of diodes.  If you really want to know what's going on pop the plastic shell off and have a look at the diode.  It may say, or it may just have a part number you could look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked a lot at 785 nm (e.g., for Rb spectroscopy).  I can assure you anyone can see this.  It's a lovely deep shade of red.  However, according to wikipedia most TV remotes use a 940 nm diode.  That is not visible by humans. Even my 800 nm diodes are invisible. You could always take it apart and see what diode is used.

Answer (score 0):

See [this post on the Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321780/if-infrared-not-visible-why-the-red-leds) for a fuller answer

Light from a remote is not just a single frequency, but remotes emit a wider range of frequencies; both due to the difficulty in producing just a single frequency of light and also to carry signals.

IR Remotes output near-IR light.  Because it is difficult to emit a single frequency of light (using a laser is one way to emit a single frequency) and the technology behind the LED, the remote produces something similar to a [Normal Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) of frequencies.  Given that the remotes output near-IR light, this means some of this distribution will fall into the visible spectrum.

[See also](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/56175/ir-rays-over-carrier-frequency-of-34khz) for another type of remote  frequency

Again, please see [this post on the Electronics StackExchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/321780/if-infrared-not-visible-why-the-red-leds) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Emission of any light source (like the IR LED) is not just a single frequency - it is a distribution of frequency, peaking at one of them. A laser diode for example emits pretty much at one precise wavelength, so its light is quite monochromatic. Thermal sources like light bulbs have a very broad spectrum and emit a large portion of the visible spectrum at once - we see a white-ish mixed light. LEDs are somewhere in between mostly and emit with a spectral FWHM (full width at half maximum) of around 100nm. So, when an LED is specified as $\lambda = 950~nm$, it's effectively emitting between 900 and 1000nm. Here is an example of the spectrum of a typical IR LED.

[image]

This not only goes for emission, but also for absorption. Our eyes use cones and rods to distinguish colours and brightness. The cones, responsible for colour, are sensitive in a certain wavelength range, not only at one specific wavelength.

[image]

**So why can you see the light from the LED?** You are seeing the bluest part of the emission spectrum, and it is dim, because your red-cones already have a very low, but non-zero, sensitivity in this wavelength area.